# Convert pandas df from long to wide and then into a sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have this dataset:

```
ARTID    INFO_1         INFO_2 
00001   some_info_11   some_info_21
00002   some_info_12   some_info_22
00003   some_info_13   some_info_23
```

and I want to transform like this

```
ARTID    some_info_11  some_info_12   some_info_13   some_info_21   some_info_22 some_info_23
00001      1                 0           0              1                0             0
00002      0                 1           0              0                1             0
```

but I need to be a sparse matrix. What's the most "memory friendly" way to do this?

Comment: you need get dummies for this purpose, check answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.ARTID,pd.get_dummies(df[['INFO_1','INFO_2']],prefix='',prefix_sep='')],axis=1)

print(df1)
  ARTID  some_info_11  some_info_12  some_info_13  some_info_21  \
0 00001             1             0             0             1   
1 00002             0             1             0             0   
2 00003             0             0             1             0   

   some_info_22  some_info_23  
0             0             0  
1             1             0  
2             0             1
```

If you `ARTID` as an index is allowed , you can use:

```
pd.get_dummies(df[['INFO_1','INFO_2']],prefix='',prefix_sep='').set_index(df.ARTID)

             some_info_11  some_info_12  some_info_13  some_info_21  some_info_22  \
ARTID                                                                         
00001                 1             0             0             1             0   
00002                 0             1             0             0             1   
00003                 0             0             1             0             0   

          some_info_23  
ARTID                
00001                 0  
00002                 0  
00003                 1
```

Comment: Rather than using `concat`, you can add `set_index(df.ARTID)`

Comment: @yatu : Thanks for the suggestion, added to the edit. :)